# Artefacts plotting DSolve solutions

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

[image]I am solving a third degree equation with DSolve, giving me 3 solutions which plotted together bring to a "tilted" Lorentzian.

```
sol=DSolve[{5/2*1/((x/0.12-y[x])^2+1)==y[x]},y,x];
Bist=Plot[Evaluate[y[x]/.sol],{x,0.217,0.228},PlotRange->{0.65,1.8},Axes->{True,False},Frame->True,FrameLabel->{"\[CapitalDelta]" , "A"},
PlotStyle->{Black,Black,Dashed,{Green,Dashed}},AspectRatio->1/2]
```

The problem is that, depending on the plot range in x, the graph gives weird spikes and/or holes here and there (I chose here a plot range that gives 2 nasty spikes as an example). I guess the problem is given by some numerical errors. 
Any idea how to make sure the plot always turn out smooth, without having to change the x range until you get a decent plot??

Comment: If I change your `/0.12` to `/(12/100)` to let `DSolve` use fully symbolic methods then your `Plot` is empty because `sol` includes complex numbers. If I plot `ReIm[y[x]]/.sol` and get rid of `PlotRange` and all your other plot decorations then I get VERY different plots from what you are showing. Can you use some of this to help focus on the problem?

Comment: `FunctionDomain[#, x] & /@ (y[x] /. sol)` evaluates to 

`{-0.207843 < x < 0.207845 || x >= 0.31255, False, False}`. 

So the solutions are generally not real-valued and none are within the plot range `{x, 0.217, 0.228}`

Answer (score 3):

```
ClearAll[sol, x, y]
sol = DSolve[{5/2/((100 x/12 - y[x])^2 + 1) == y[x]}, y, x];
Bist = Plot[Evaluate[ReIm[y[x]] /. sol], {x, -.7, .7}, 
  Axes -> {True, False}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"Δ", "A"}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Black, Black, Dashed, {Green, Dashed}}]
```

[image: Output]

The real part of the solution by `DSolve`:
    sol = DSolve[{5/2/((100 x/12 - y[x])^2 + 1) == y[x]}, y, x];
    Bist = Plot[Evaluate[Re[y[x]] /. sol], {x, -.7, .7}, 
      Axes -> {True, False}, Frame -> True, 
      FrameLabel -> {"Δ", "A"}, 
      PlotStyle -> {Black, Black, Dashed, {Green, Dashed}}]
[[image: Output]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJ2G8.png)

This is not a Lorentzian curve. There are no such dips.

```
sol = DSolve[{5/2/((100 x/12 - y[x])^2 + 1) == y[x]}, y, x];
Bist = Plot[Evaluate[Im[y[x]] /. sol], {x, -.7, .7}, 
  Axes -> {True, False}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"Δ", "A"}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Black, Black, Dashed, {Green, Dashed}}]
```

[image: Output]

Discarding the PlotStyle:

```
Bist = Plot[Evaluate[Re[y[x]] /. sol], {x, -.7, .7}, 
  Axes -> {True, False}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"Δ", "A"}]
```

[image: Output]
gives a rather different impression.

Using the parts of the solution:

```
Bist = Plot[Evaluate[Re[y[x]] /. First@sol], {x, -.7, .7}, 
  Axes -> {True, False}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"Δ", "A"}]
```

[image: Output]

```
Bist = Plot[Evaluate[Re[y[x]] /. sol[[2]]], {x, -.7, .7}, 
  Axes -> {True, False}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"Δ", "A"}]
```

[image: Output]

```
Bist = Plot[Evaluate[Re[y[x]] /. sol[[3]]], {x, -.7, .7}, 
  Axes -> {True, False}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"Δ", "A"}]
```

[image: Output]

So the contour looking like a Lorentzian is compose of all the parts of the solutions calculated by Mathematica `DSolve`.

All three real solutions make up the curves.

Without the ReIm, Re, or IM I get constant solutions in the shown region. That is a matter of the internal methodologies.

```
sol = DSolve[{5/2/((100 x/12 - y[x])^2 + 1) == y[x]}, y, x];
Bist = Plot[Evaluate[y[x] /. sol], {x, -.7, .7}, 
  Axes -> {True, False}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"Δ", "A"}]
```

[image: Output]
gives a closer solutions representation to Yours. It discarted the `PlotStyle` to show up again the arms, parts of the solutions. Now there is again a spike that is mathematically part of the not drawn jump of the first solution, the this solution arm is rejected internally by Mathematica and the second solution is followed.

Since the jumps to not really belong to the solution this is a false part of it, but can not be removed. There is an internal precision used that can be made smaller to get more exact results. That consumes more time.

Your choice can be made more real:

```
sol = DSolve[{5/2/((100 x/12 - y[x])^2 + 1) == y[x]}, y, x, 
   Assumptions -> x ∈ Reals];
Bist = Plot[Evaluate[y[x] /. sol], {x, -.7, .7}, 
  Axes -> {True, False}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"Δ", "A"}]
```

[image: Output]

The main problem is the given equation is not a differential equation. It is an equation.

It ought to be handled this way:

```
sol = Solve[5/2/((100 x/12 - y)^2 + 1) == y && x == a, {x, y}, Reals]
Bist = Plot[Evaluate[Re[y /. sol]], {a, -1, 1}, Axes -> {True, False},
   Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"Δ", "A"}]
```

[image: Output]

And in this `Plot`, the precision problem with `DSolve` is gone! The small gap can, therefore, be filled with it. The arms, branches remain but be more "physical" in the sense of interpretation as a Lorentzian asymmetric profile.

Comment: That's it! That's the type alternative I was hoping to find! Thanks!